# How do I turn fields from my database into variables using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to pull title and price of an item from my database and turn them into variables - $title and $price so that I can use them elsewhere in the code.

Here is my statement so far:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title, price FROM book WHERE b_id=$book");
$sth->execute();
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I haven't specified or declared any variables yet.  I want to put the results for title and price from the SELECT query into a new variable.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to fetch results after `->execute()`tion. And please, use the API properly, when you're using prepared statements, bind the variables, don't use your variables straight up on the query string.

Prepare the statement including those placeholders.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT title, price FROM book WHERE b_id = :book');
$sth->bindValue(':book', $book);
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!empty($results)) {
    $title = $results['title'];
    $price = $results['price'];
}
```

Comment: @Enjoyted it defeats the purpose of having it prepared, thats why you use prepared statements, you bind the variables, not using them directly into the query

Comment: Well yeah, just said that because you answer was after Vicky's one but was overall better.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  I understand why it's important to bind now.

Comment: @stark yes, always remember to bind those values when using prepare. glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `title`, `price` FROM `book` WHERE `b_id`='".$book."'");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$title=$result['title'];
$price=$result['price'];
```

Comment: maybe you should use the binding. like 'WHERE b_id = ?; $sth->execute(array($book));

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)?

*This solution is for more than 1 result.*

```
$title=array();
$price=array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $title[]=$row['title'];
    $price[]=$row['price'];
}
```

**If you need it for 1 price and title, check ghost his answer.**

Answer (score 1):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title, price FROM book WHERE b_id=:book");
$sth->bindParam(":book",$book);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$title=$result['title'];
$price=$result['price'];
```

It's PDO so dont forget to bindParam() your vars.